# Twitter api c# newbie

Tags: api, twitter

I need to build a application on c# .net

Need to get tweets with hashtag "happy" and display them in a textbox ,

Now with http request i get only 10 tweets , any one can suggest how to use twitter api and where to download it , please need complete follow steps as i am a newbie over this.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to get the data from Twitter, you need follow so step.

1. Implement a function to get Access Token.
2. Implement a function to search the data via API.

Noted: I not sure you still need the support, so if you need some helps please comment and i will help you.